# Outer Measure of a Finite Covering of the Rationals on $[0, 1]$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

I'm studying for my Real Analysis final and came upon an old question on outer measure that I'm pretty sure I'm doing wrong.
If $B$ is the set containing the rationals on $[0, 1]$, and $(I_k)_{k=1}^{n}$ is a finite collection of open intervals that covers $B$, how can I show that $\sum_{k=1}^{n} m^* (I_k) \ge 1$?
My attempt: assume $\sum_{k=1}^{n} m^* (I_k) \lt 1$. Then $\exists (a, b) \subseteq [0,1]$ such that $(a, b)$ is not covered by $(I_k)_{k=1}^{n}$. Then, since $(a, b) \cap B ≠ \emptyset$, $(I_k)_{k=1}^{n}$ is not a covering: contradiction.
I have a serious hunch this is totally off, since I don't use the fact that $(I_k)_{k=1}^n$ is a finite covering, and I'm pretty sure that it's needed (since obviously an infinite but countable covering for $B$ can be made arbitrarily small), but I don't know exactly where my reasoning fails. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're most of the way but you've missed out one step.

Because $\sum_{k=1}^n m^*(I_k)<1$ there exists at least one point $x\notin\bigcup_{k=1}^n m^*(I_k)$ but you need to prove that there is an open set $(a,b)\ni x$.  So think about 2 things.

1. Is it still true  that $\exists x\notin \bigcup_{k=1}^n m^*(I_k)$ if the intervals $I_n$ are closed?
2. What can you say (topologically) about the union of a finite collection of closed intervals that you can't say about a countable one.

Hope that's not too cryptic.

Comment: When you say "there exists at least one $x\notin\bigcup\ldots$" that you don't mean to have m^*$$ there. Or at least I'm thinking that $m^*\left((a,b)\right)=b-a$, am I misunderstanding the notation?